# Extjs : Need a confirmation message before closing the window

Tags: extjs, window, confirmation

I have a Ext.window and I would like to display a confirmation message before a user tries to close the window either by clicking the close button in the window or the default [x] button in the top or by Esc key. I have the following code for this purpose.

```
              closeWindow: function(){
                       Ext.Msg.show({
                      title: 'Confirm or Cancel',
                      msg: 'Are you sure you want to close this window?',
                      buttonText: {ok: 'Yes', cancel: 'No'},
                      icon: Ext.Msg.WARNING,
                      scope: this,
                      width: 400,
                      fn: function(btn, text){
                      if (btn == 'ok'){
                      clearInterval(this.myIntervalTimer);
                      this.cleanEvents(null, null, this.identifier);
                       this.view.destroy();
                    } else {
                   return;
                }
                }
             });
           }
```

This piece of code works fine when I click on the Close button in the window. But when I click the default close[x] or the esc key, due to async nature of extjs the window disappears before the confirmation message gets displayed. When the confirmation message displays there is no window and so it is becoming irrelevant. I tried using the beforeClose event as well but of no use.

Any suggestions or ideas of how this can be achieved in extjs?. Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test the following please, it works for me:

```
    Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
         title:'Test'
        ,width:400
        ,height:300
        ,autoShow:true
        ,listeners:{
            beforeclose:function(win) {
                if(win.closeMe) {
                    win.closeMe = false;
                    return true;
                }
                Ext.Msg.show({
                     title:'Close confirmation'
                    ,msg:'Really close?'
                    ,buttons:Ext.Msg.YESNO
                    ,callback:function(btn) {
                        if('yes' === btn) {
                            win.closeMe = true;
                            win.close();
                        }
                    }
                })
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I will try this and will let you know of the result. So, this listener will get called whenever the window gets closed. I have a close button in my window and what code should I be having for that close button handler in this situation because if I say this.close for that event, there is a chance that the confirmation message will get displayed 2 times, first time as part of the this.close() method in my button handler and then the default close which happens before the window closes.

Comment: It should be enough to call `win.close()` as the button handler. That fires `beforeclose` event so the whole above logic kicks in.